# Fade in image css animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an image which should fade in via animation. The opacity should be used so that it looks like it is fading in from left to right (not sliding).

I already have a good approach, but here the image is permanently visible. The animation of the white div works quite well so far.

```html
<div class="font-grotesk h-[500px] bg-gray-900">
  <div class="flex h-[100px]">
    <div class="second-logo max-w-[150px] bg-white">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/90x30" class="min-w-[150px] overflow-hidden px-[14px] py-9" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.second-logo {
  animation: showHide 3s;
}

@keyframes showHide {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }

  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/l7Vqyn2lcm

Comment: This question would be greatly helped by a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't have any of your classes and not even [an image](https://picsum.photos/). Working code would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: opacity can't do any "directional fading".

Comment: Added playground url: https://play.tailwindcss.com/91iqFprvXC

Comment: There are 2 images in your playground, I'm not sure which one your question is referring to? Anyway, as CBroe said, you cannot fade in opacity. However, you could cover the image with something else, either an image or gradient, going from opaque to transparent and slide this over the image. Hide the overflow. It will appear as if the image fades in.

Comment: I have removed the image which is not necessary and adjusted the Playground url.

Comment: Do you mean fade in, as in having opacity 0 go to opacity 1. It looks from your code that all you want to do is gradually reveal it, no opacity change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a clip path to draw in the entire div from left to right.

```css
.reveal {
  animation: reveal 600ms forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
  }

  100% {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  }
}
```